# Errno 1 Operation not permitted. But file has full permissions?

Tags: python, file-permissions, errno, operationalerror

Doing a project that I reworked to include an Sqlite database. Had no problem accessing, reading and writing files before with pickle, within the same directory, and even in other more root directories within the program files. But now after redevelopment, I am pulling Errno1 telling me that

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(dataBase)
OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

[image: Full permissions]

So I checked permissions like everyone recommended, and I have full permission for the file.
Unable to figure it out I created a test.txt file to see if I could open that file from my console.

```
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: /Users/daniel/Documents/PROJECTS/DANTRON/DATA_LOG/CONTROL_DATABASE/test.txt
```

Again checked permissions and I have full permissions. Even added both read and write permissions to admin and everyone, just to be sure. Still unable to open the file and still getting an Errno 1.

[image: Full permission on test.txt]

I tried changing the permissions via the terminal, and checked the groups and noticed something odd. Someone mentioned it is normal to see a group with the same name as the user, but I found a lot of groups but none with my user name. Don't know if this is meaningful. Tried chown, and it still isn't allowing me.

[image]

How can I figure this out?

UPDATE:

So I used

```
os.getcwd()
```

to find the working directory of the terminal, and tried to open a file within the same working directory, and I was successful. Seems to me the problem is that I can't open any files that are not in my current working directory. I've never had this problem in the past with python, and don't remember ever having to make adjustments to access files outside of the current working directory.

[Unable to open files outside Dir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBOAD.png)

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can fix this problem?

Comment: There may be restrictions on what you can do with iCloud Drive. Try copying the file to a local folder.

Answer (score 0):

can it be that the ICloud Drive is the reason ?
Try a folder outside that ICloud Drive scope ....

Comment: The whole computer is stored in i-cloud drive. It automatically backs up any files etc. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm able to open files within my working directory, but unable to open any files outside of my working directory. Any solutions?